# Get text from a class table and text having bold value using beufitulsoup

Tags: python, parsing

here my codes :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url= 'http://someurl'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
```

If I extract a table from that url

```
for loc in soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'class1'}):
     print loc.text
```

will result :

```
(1:1:1) text that having bold attribute, example BEE and ANT
(1:1:2) other text is a CAT
(1:1:3) here a DOG
(1:1:4) else is a TIGER
```

(1:1:1), etc  have class : addrs on a span so if do this code :

```
tabel= soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'class1'})
 for lok in tabel.findAll('span', attrs={'class':'addrs'}):
    print lok.text
```

will result :

```
(1:1:1)
(1:1:2)
(1:1:3)
(1:1:4)
```

and the code :

```
for loki in tabel.findAll('b'):
    print loki.text
```

will result :
    BEE
    ANT
    CAT
    DOG
    TIGER

The text that I want is,

```
(1:1:1) BEE - ANT
(1:1:2) CAT
(1:1:3) DOG
(1:1:4) TIGER
```

Comment: You need to clarify a bit. Are you trying to print anything that is in UPPERCASE in the original table?

Comment: No, I edited the question now for clarify,